# "He can not be helped."?

Tags: idioms, passive-voice

> "He can not be helped."

Is this possible and a way of saying that the person, he in this case, has no chance of being helped? (I'm not sure if "being helped" is possible either) 
I think "It can't be helped" is a set phrase but I didn't find anything beside that. Would I have to phrase this in the active voice? "You can't help him" "There is no help for him/ no helping him."

Comment: There's no point in helping him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those are possible. "He cannot be helped" is grammatical, and reads perfectly normally. But, as you say, there is an idiom "It cannot be helped" which gets in the way, and may confuse hearers.

Comment: Actually, now I think about it "He won't be helped" might be a better rendering. It's an odd one, because it preserves the archaic use of "won't" = "doesn't want to", and it implies that not being able to be helped is something that is deliberate on his part; but that very often fits the case. And it is idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

You might try:

> He is a lost cause.

"I've tried to help Tyler with his drug problem but he is a lost cause." [Source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lost%20cause)